# Multi foreign key's in table with CakePHP

Tags: database-design, cakephp-2.0, mode

I have one situation where i want to take 3 foreign keys in one table. 
And associate that table with 3 models. Is that a good practice to follow with CakePHP?

e.g. I have User, Roles, Multiple Modules :

Now user has one role with roles_users. User has many modules with many Roles inside the modules, So i want to create another table modules_users_roles, which will be associated to the user, module & role..

Please let me know is it right way to add 3 foreign keys in one table?
or do i need to brake it in,

module_users with id, user_id, module_id 
module_user_roles with id module_user_is, role_id

But this will complicate the associations & data fetching from the DB

Answer (score 1):

Well a bit of context would have been more helpful.

You can have "Roles" foreign key in User.

But if the situation really demands having multiple foreign keys there isn't much you can do.

Just do keep your "recursive" level at check while doing finds.